# Shiny App Secure Server Causes Server Disconnect and Instability

Tags: r, shiny

I have a large Shiny app that performs some basic data transformations, creates reports, and sends emails. The only thing that may be slightly unusual about the app is that it reads and writes to google sheet (using googlesheets4).

We've decided to implement a user authentication for the app using "shinymanager". The authentication works fine, but shortly after logging in the app disconnects from the server. There are no errors in the shinyapps.io log. When I check the Chrome browser console I get this error when the app disconnects from the server:

**Connection closed. Info: {"type":"close","code":4702,"reason":"Error reading from Shiny","wasClean":true}**

This is the line of code in the server that is causing the instability, when I remove it the app runs smoothly.

```
result_auth <- secureserver(check credentials = check credentials(credentials))
```

I know I didn't provide a reproducible example but I'm not sure how to do that in a useful manner in this case. Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening and/or potential solutions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try instead `result_auth <- secure_server(check_credentials = check_credentials(credentials))`, from the example https://datastorm-open.github.io/shinymanager/#usage

Comment: @mhovd thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, the app still disconnects from the server a few seconds after the authentication.